# replace npm start by what it redirects to

Tags: npm, npm-start

I am testing a code and in the .json file there is:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build"
}
```

The code works well when I run

```
npm start
```

in the console.

But `npm start` shall be a shortcut. If I write:

```
react-scripts start
```

instead in the console it doesn't work. My error message is

```
react-scripts: command not found
```

Why? It is not equivalent? And if react-scripts is not found how does using `npm start` works?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any defined npm script exexcuted by `npm run` will look for executionable binaries from with

```
cd your_project
./node_modules/.bin
```

folder first. You can also see its full path via:

```
npm bin
```

These binaries are coming from your project's defined dependencies from the `package.json` via `npm install`.

`npm run start` is hence euquivalent to running:

```
./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start
```

When you try to run

```
react-scripts start
```

on its own, you terminal will only look up your system's `PATH` and try to find it there.

```
echo $PATH
```

So if you have `react-scripts` only installed locally and not globally, it won't find the executable binary, and hence fail.

If you want to run it globally, you have to install it globally:

```
npm install -g react-scripts
which react-scripts
~/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/react-scripts //
```

and `~/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin` is part of my PATH.

---

Sidenotes:

I prefer having each project define its own  dependencies with their specific version locally and only use that. As you might have multiple projects dependending on different version of a binary.

And if you consistently use the one defined in the `package.json`, you won't run into problems.

It also prevents "works on my machine" problems with co-workers when your npm script consistently rebuilds the state.

With npm it's a bit messy as you either define all the dependencies libraries you want to use in the npm scripts, or you have to run each command like:

```
$(npm bin)/yourCmd
```

Since I also like using [`yarn`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) as my npm replacement, I grew fond of its default to always look into the project's  bin folder in order to execute a cmd via:

```
yarn yourCmd
$ "/home/philipp/my-project/node_modules/.bin/yourCmd"
```